# awk calculate the difference with last row and create new column with value

Tags: awk

I have a file like this :

```
time,VALUE
2022-02-02 00:00:39,57
2022-02-02 00:01:39,58
2022-02-02 00:02:39,59
2022-02-02 00:03:39,59
2022-02-02 00:04:40,62
2022-02-02 00:05:40,60
```

And I would like (maybe the better choice is awk) to create a new column which calculate the difference with last row. Example :

```
time,VALUE,Diff
2022-02-02 00:00:39,57,0
2022-02-02 00:01:39,58,1
2022-02-02 00:02:39,59,1
2022-02-02 00:03:39,59,0
2022-02-02 00:04:40,62,3
2022-02-02 00:05:40,60,-2
```

I have this little script  `awk 'NR==1{s=$1;next}{print $1-s;s=$1}'` but I don't know how to easily add a new colum with results and to add a '0' for the first line

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define special rules for the first two lines

```
awk -F "," -v OFS="," 'NR==1{print $0,"Diff"} 
                       NR==2{print $0,0} 
                       NR>2{print $0,$2-last} {last=$2}' file
time,VALUE,Diff
2022-02-02 00:00:39,57,0
2022-02-02 00:01:39,58,1
2022-02-02 00:02:39,59,1
2022-02-02 00:03:39,59,0
2022-02-02 00:04:40,62,3
2022-02-02 00:05:40,60,-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
NR==1 {print $0,"Diff"; next}
      {print $0,(NR==2 ? 0 : $2-last); last=$2}
' file
```

This generates:

```
time,VALUE,Diff
2022-02-02 00:00:39,57,0
2022-02-02 00:01:39,58,1
2022-02-02 00:02:39,59,1
2022-02-02 00:03:39,59,0
2022-02-02 00:04:40,62,3
2022-02-02 00:05:40,60,-2
```

Comment: duplicate `$2` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '
time,VALUE
2022-02-02 00:00:39,57
2022-02-02 00:01:39,58
2022-02-02 00:02:39,59
2022-02-02 00:03:39,59
2022-02-02 00:04:40,62
2022-02-02 00:05:40,60' |
```

---

```
mawk 'BEGIN { _ += _^= FS = OFS =  "," (__ = "") 
            } ($++NF = NR<_ ? "Diff" : -__ + (__ = $_)*(_ < NR))_'
```

---

```
time,VALUE,Diff
2022-02-02 00:00:39,57,0
2022-02-02 00:01:39,58,1
2022-02-02 00:02:39,59,1
2022-02-02 00:03:39,59,0
2022-02-02 00:04:40,62,3
2022-02-02 00:05:40,60,-2
```